# jquery addClass and cookie

Tags: jquery, cookies, addclass

I am having a hard time figuring out how to keep the jquery addClass function on a link when I click to another page. I've read I can do it with cookies but I am not a javascript developer and I can't write the code myself.

I have this page here:

http://www.nationallighting.ie/testbed/index.php/products

When I click on one of the categories on the left sidebar, the content scrolls to that category and the link is highlighted. However, when I click on a single product inside that category, I go to another page that's the single product page and the link on the left sidebar is not highlighted anymore, i.e.:

http://www.nationallighting.ie/testbed/index.php/products-single/bmywz220

How can I still keep the link highlighted when I click on the single product page?

here is my very long jquery script (again, I am not a javascript developer so I do what I can...)

```
    // Products hover and active state
$(function(){
$(".sidebar-products ul li a").click(function(){
$(this).addClass('active');
$('a.active').not(this).removeClass('active');
});
});
$(function(){
$("a.outdoor").click(function(){
$('.sidebar-products ul li a.outdoor').addClass('active');
$('a.active').not('.sidebar-products ul li a.outdoor').removeClass('active');
});
});
$(function(){
$("a.wall").click(function(){
$('.sidebar-products ul li a.wall').addClass('active');
$('a.active').not('.sidebar-products ul li a.wall').removeClass('active');
});
});
$(function(){
$("a.bathroom").click(function(){
$('.sidebar-products ul li a.bathroom').addClass('active');
$('a.active').not('.sidebar-products ul li a.bathroom').removeClass('active');
});
});
$(function(){
$("a.centre").click(function(){
$('.sidebar-products ul li a.centre').addClass('active');
$('a.active').not('.sidebar-products ul li a.centre').removeClass('active');
});
});
$(function(){
$("a.pendents").click(function(){
$('.sidebar-products ul li a.pendents').addClass('active');
$('a.active').not('.sidebar-products ul li a.pendents').removeClass('active');
});
});
$(function(){
$("a.crystal").click(function(){
$('.sidebar-products ul li a.crystal').addClass('active');
$('a.active').not('.sidebar-products ul li a.crystal').removeClass('active');
});
});
$(function(){
$("a.table").click(function(){
$('.sidebar-products ul li a.table').addClass('active');
$('a.active').not('.sidebar-products ul li a.table').removeClass('active');
});
});
$(function(){
$("a.spots").click(function(){
$('.sidebar-products ul li a.spots').addClass('active');
$('a.active').not('.sidebar-products ul li a.spots').removeClass('active');
});
});
$(function(){
$(".sidebar-about ul li a").click(function(){
$(this).addClass('active');
$('a.active').not(this).removeClass('active');
});
});
```

Any help really appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Dumping all this code is not too helpful. You better create a small test case.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need cookies to accomplish this, there are a few options out there.

1. Add a cookie that indicates the current category, as you asked. You can use for example [this](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) jQuery plugin to easily change cookies. But now you might create extra problems because you'll have to remove this cookie at the correct moments (maybe when you load the product page).
2. If your product can only be assigned to one category, you know the category and you can easily add this class when creating your HTML (you'll do this at server side).
3. You can add a query string to your URL (?category=MYCATEGORY) and based upon that you can add the class to your menu item (possible at both server side and client side).

Comment: That all depends on your code base and your data. You retrieve your data from the database, just retrieve the category as well in. And then in your HTML creation (Views?), where you create your menu, you just check (IF statement) whether the category in the menu matches the category of your product and if so, add the class to the menu item.

Comment: thanks Styxxy, it all sounds a bit too complicated for me but I'll try and figure it out!

Comment: It is not too complicated, but it needs a little knowledge about the technologies.

Answer (score 0):

Insert this piece of code to your click events

```
$.cookie("category", 'categoryname');
```

this will set the cookie every time you click the menu item, after that you'll able to asign the active css class to the appropriate item. I noticed that all your links have designated classes already, so if you chose to use the same name for your cookie you'll be able to do something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.'+$.cookie("category")).addClass('activeclass')
}
```

This should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks roacher, it's still not working...

here's what I have:

    $(function(){
 $("a.gotoitem").click(function(){
 $(".sidebar-about ul li a").addClass('active');
 $.cookie("category", 'categoryname');
 });
 });
    $(document).ready(function() {
 $('a.'+$.cookie("category")).addClass('active')
    })

where am I wrong?

Comment: mate, in $.cookie("category", 'categoryname'); });  this line you're using the string 'categoryname' as opposed to the real cateogory name :) My code was just an example, you're supposed to replace the string with whatever fits your needs. As in, for each button, when you're biding your other events, you add for an example $.cookie("category", 'outside');